# IE9 Standard mode and Compability View mode alignment

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the following aspx code fragment.  In the IE9 standard mode, even there is nothing to the left of the 1st listLabel, the 1st listLabel would still flush to the right and forces down one line for the remaining listLabels and their ListBoxes.  In IE9 compatibility view mode, all listLabels and ListBoxes are on the same line.  I tried many css settings without success.  I prefer not to use float.  Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix the problem? Thanks.

```
label.listLable
{
    /*vertical-align:top;*/
    font-weight:bold;
}


    <asp:Content ID="pageContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
        <div>
            <div>
                <label for="<%=listPcpPanel.ClientID%>" class="listLable">Panel: </label>
                <asp:ListBox ID="listPcpPanel" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="1">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="&lt;----- All -----&gt;" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
                <label for="<%=listFacilityService.ClientID%>" class="listLable">Service: </label>
                 <asp:ListBox ID="listFacilityService" runat="server" SelectionMode="Single" Visible="true" Rows="1">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="&lt;---Select one---&gt;" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
                <label for="<%=listRole.ClientID%>" class="listLable">Role: </label>
                <asp:ListBox ID="listRole" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Visible="true" Rows="1">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="&lt;----- All -----&gt;" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
            </div>
        ...
        ...
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Please upload a screenshot if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by removing the first <div> child of the <asp:content>.